# Why is WNDCLASS (Windows-C) setup and used like so?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

In creating a window:

1) Why should we register the window class and how does `CreateWindow` understand our desired class?

```
WNDCLASS wc;
RegisterClass(&wc)
```

2) Why should we use this LOOP:

```
MSG msg;
While(GetMessage(&msg,0,0,0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispathMessage(&msg);
}
```

At start there is no messsage, so we won’t enter the loop and we will exit from the `WinMain` function.

Comment: @fred you have the rep to fix the spelling

Comment: @David I fixed some, don't know if that's what you were thinking of?

Answer (score 7):

You register the window class because that's how the system works. Think of it as defining a type. GetMessage blocks until a message arrives in the queue.

You really need to read Charles Petzold's book, [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/index.html)

Comment: Link to the book in question?

Comment: @pst I'm on my phone. Typing is hard. Book is called Programming Windows. Easy to find. Please feel free to edit my answer I would not mind!

Answer (score 2):

In principle when your program starts up you tell Windows that your window/program is ready to accept messages - that is registering it. The message loop thereafter is where the interaction with the user (and system) happens. Every time some interaction is needed it is communicated to the application via a message (or event). In your message loop you define behavior how to react on the different messages.

Besides the UI messages there are other messages like timer event or messages system related messages. These can be handled as well.

Comment: window class registering is not about saying that you are ready to start. It defines a window type, principally through the window proc.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a wrong assumption about `GetMessage`. You state that if there's no message, "we won’t enter the loop". That means you assume `GetMessage` returns false if there's no message.

In fact, `GetMessage` returns false only when there's a `WM_QUIT` message. If there is no message, `GetMessage` *does not return*. It just waits until a message does arrive. This makes a lot of sense for many programs. If there's no input, there's nothing to do and your program doesn't need CPU time.

Some programs periodically need some CPU time. That's why they use `WM_TIMER`: so that `GetMessage` returns control to your code.